# What is the newline character in Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, oracle10g, char, newline

Running in sqldeveloper, this prompts an empty cell in the results

```
select regexp_replace(chr(10) || chr(13), '\n', 'New Line')
from dual
```

I was expecting this to be `'_New Line'` or `'New Line_'` but instead I get `'__'` (Note that underscore is visually an empty space).

This doesn't work either.

```
select regexp_replace(
  UNISTR('\000A') 
  || UNISTR('\000D')
  , '\n', 'New Line')
from dual
```

Specifically I need this to work in java. There is a method that will invoque a stored procedure that returns a cursor with columns that may have line breakings. From the java side I need this to work:

```
String or = resultset.getString("some_column"); // null check left for simplicity    
... = or.split("\\n"); 
... = or.split("\\r?\\n");
```

I was testing with regexp_replace because it is supposed to do the same.

Comment: What do you mean, work in Java? You're running this query from Java, or you will have a fixed string query you pass, or you'll provide the substitutions from the Java side? You'll need to give more context of what you're executing, e.g some sample Java code and expected outcome...

Comment: @AlexPoole Edited accordingly, thanks for your attention.

Comment: The new line character coming back from Oracle is the same as the new line character in Java; `chr(10)` and `\n` are the same thing, they are just how the two languages represent that character. So... what you are doing with `split` should be working.

Comment: Tested with a small Java program. If I have a query that returns `'abc'||chr(10)||'def'`, then both your `split` examples split it into two Strings in the array. `regexp_replace` would let you change the value on the server side, but that doesn't help you get the single value into an array of values. It would let you use a different character for your `split`, I suppose, but that just seems confusing?

Answer (score 0):

You're already using the newline character, it's `chr(10)`:

```
select regexp_replace('<'||chr(10) || chr(13)||'>', chr(10), 'New Line')
from dual;
```

To replace the line feed instead, use `chr(13)`.

You don't need to use a regular expression here, you can use the normal `replace()` instead.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/22138) with angle brackets added to show the output more clearly.